# Google Maps Android not working with exactly the same code as yesterday

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I'm implementing this Android Maps application in android. At this moment, it is very simple and just displays a map, zooms in to the user's current location and places a red circle around him. I'm using Google Maps API for Android v2.

Here is an exctract of the class that shows the map. It used to run well yesterday, but today, the same code doesn't work.

```
public class OpenMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap mapView;
    com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection projection;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private float lat=40.0f;
    private float lng=40.0f;
    long startTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frame);
    FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    MapFragmentD mFRaFragment = new MapFragmentD();
    mFRaFragment.setActivity(this);
    mTransaction.add(R.id.mainl, mFRaFragment);
    mTransaction.commit();

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.draggable(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lat=(float) location.getLatitude();
    lng=(float) location.getLongitude();

    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
    mapView.addMarker(markerOptions);
    Log.d("CORDS", Float.toString(lat));
    mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     LatLng loc= new LatLng(lat,lng);

    mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));

}
...
```

}

I don't know if the error is in the settings, build path, Google API key or something else. Did Google deprecate v2 of Android Maps API? Anyway, here is an extract of the LogCat error messages:

```
11-23 18:33:59.417: E/Google Maps Android API(6558): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.    
11-23 18:33:59.417: E/Google Maps Android API(6558): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.test, API Key: <key value>, Certificate Fingerprint: <fingerprint value>
11-23 18:33:59.427: I/Google Maps Android API(6558): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
```

Anybody had any similar problems and in that case, how did you fix them? Yes, I have looked at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start but it either doesn't contain the solution, or I'm not smart enough to extract it. I'm completelly new to Android programming so I don't now where to start looking for the solution, the Java code, XML files, build setup, or API version.

Comment: I have, it is the same as before and the same as google api console shows me. What more precisely am I supposed to check for? Can I see if it is invalid somewhere in Google API console?

Comment: Try the api key in addressbar of browser with some google url

Answer (score 1):

After many hours debugging I found the solution. It wasn't the java code, it wasn't the xml files, and it wasn't the key. Apparently, I had turned on WiFi on my phone and when WiFi is on, the app can't access the map (even though mobile broadband is activated) without a special permission. Everything else runs great in the app even with WiFi activated. When I turn off WiFi, everything works as yesterday.

That one was a little bit hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Is most likely that your Eclipse's debug key has expired and now you have a brand new one. Try updating the hash and all the necessary info on your Google Console/API Console to match the new one.

Extra info: The last time I checked, the lifetime expectancy of the debug key was 1 year.

Comment: How long time are these keys valid anyway? I created it no longer than two weeks ago. When I look in Preferences>Build inside Eclipse ADT, the SHA1 fingerprint is exactly the same as when I log on to Google API Console. Since the hash didn't change, why should I change the key and what do I change it to? Thankful for any help, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Then that's not the problem. The last time I checked, the lifetime expectancy of the keys was 1 year.